# Oracle - Doing an update with an Inner Join and Partition?

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, sql-update

I have a table that looks like the following called HIST:

```
+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
|      ID       |    MGROUP     |  ACTIVESTATUS  |  FROM_DATE  |   TO_DATE   |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
|  86183752530  |  30546        |  Inactive      |  09-MAR-09  |  05-SEP-09  |
|  86183752533  |  30546        |  Active        |  05-SEP-09  |  29-SEP-09  |
|  86183752534  |  30546        |  Inactive      |  29-SEP-09  |  (null)     |
|  86369271439  |  85764511006  |  Active        |  19-OCT-10  |  (null)     |
|  86369271447  |  85851006389  |  Active        |  16-NOV-10  |  (null)     |
|  86369271517  |  86369271513  |  Active        |  25-JAN-11  |  (null)     |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
```

This table is used to record the history of the group. For example we can see MGROUP 30546 went Inactive on 09-MAR-09 to 05-SEP-09 and then went active again on 05-SEP-09 TO 29-SEP-09. Then finally went Inactive again on 29-SEP-09 and is currently this way till any future updates ( null ).

Now i have another table that looks like the following called GROUP:

```
+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
|      M_NAME       |     ID      | ACTIVESTATUS |
+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
| Jack Smith        |       30546 | Inactive     |
| John Doe          | 85764511006 | Active       |
| Bobby Drop Tables | 85851006389 | Active       |
+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I have written a Select Statement that does what I want to do:

```
    select
    m_name,
    hist.to_date,
    SYSDATE AS new_hist_to_date
    from group
    inner join
    (
        select 
        mgroup, 
        from_date, 
        to_date,  
        rowNumber
        from 
        (
          select 
          mgroup, 
          from_date, 
          to_date, activestatus, row_number() over ( partition by mgroup order by to_date desc nulls first) rowNumber
          from hist
        )
        where rowNumber = 1
    ) hist ON hist.MGROUP = group.id
where m_mgroup.ACTIVESTATUS = "Inactive"
```

Any attempts I have made to convert this into an update statement has failed. What I am trying to do is set the table HIST.TO_DATE to SYSDATE if table GROUP.ACTIVESTATUS = Inactive.

What is a good way of doing this?

Comment: Simple: `UPDATE hist SET to_date = sysdate  WHERE EXIST( SELECT 1 FROM group WHERE hist.mgroup = group.id and group.activestatus = 'Inactive')` doesn't work? Or, maybe:  `UPDATE (SELECT * FROM hist JOIN group ON hist.mgroup = group.id and group.activestatus = 'Inactive' ) SET to_date = sysdate `

Comment: @kordirko Sorry if I didn't mention it in the comments but I need to grab the latest date for each mgroup with null being the highest. This is why I do the:
row_number() over ( partition by mgroup order by to_date desc nulls first) rowNumber
          from hist
        )
        where rowNumber = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laziest approach is to select rowids from your query, and do something like this:

```
UPDATE hist SET ....
WHERE rowid IN (  your query )
```

I created [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f54ab/1) to demonstrate this.

The query might look like:

```
UPDATE hist
set to_date = sysdate
where rowid in (
    select hist_rowid 
 from (       
        select rowid hist_rowid,
        mgroup, 
        from_date, 
        to_date,  
        rowNumber
        from 
        (
          select 
          mgroup, 
          from_date, 
          to_date, activestatus, row_number() over ( partition by mgroup order by to_date desc nulls first) rowNumber
          from hist
        )
        where rowNumber = 1
  ) hist
  join "GROUP" ON hist.MGROUP = "GROUP".id AND "GROUP".ACTIVESTATUS = 'Inactive'
);
```

GROUP is reserved word in Oracle, so I surrounded name of GROUP table with "" to avoid syntax errors

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at it tomorrow and will post the results. Group was not the table name I just named it in the example and wasn't thinking.